# Can I tell NDepend to ignore a single result?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ndepend

I'm running NDepend against my C# project in VS 2012.  There is a particular "critical rule violation" that I have looked at and have decided that I want to leave as-is.  I want to tell NDepend to ignore this one violation and NOT count it against my critical rule violation count, so that I can get the dot at the bottom to be no longer red.

If it matters: It's a "function with too many parameters".  The purpose of function is to make a log entry into a database table, and I need to pass in all of the values (11 of them) to populate the table (after applying some logic to them).  I suppose I could put all the values into a struct or class and pass that in as a single value, but there would be no other use for the struct/class than to call this one function, so that seems kind of silly to me.

So, I was looking for a way to just do something like right-clicking on the result and choosing "permanently ignore this result", like you might do with a spell checker, but I don't see any such option.

Is there a way to do this?

I don't want to exclude the entire rule or modify it to increase the max number of parameters, as there may be other instances where I DO agree that the function should be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the CQLinq rule body this way:

```
// <Name>Methods with too many parameters</Name>
warnif count > 0 from m in JustMyCode.Methods
.WithFullNameNotIn("MyNamespace.MyType.MyMethod1(String,Int32,Int32,Boolean,String,Int32,Int32,Boolean,String,Int32,Int32,Boolean)", 
                   "MyNamespace.MyType.MyMethod2(String,Int32,Int32,Boolean,String,Int32,Int32,Boolean,String,Int32,Int32,Boolean)",
                   ...)
where 
  m.NbParameters > 5 
  orderby m.NbParameters descending
select new { m, m.NbParameters }
```

Notice that the rule body contains the *method(s) to exclude* full names. To get the method full name, just right click the method in the result and choose the menu *Copy name to clipboard*.

[image: Exclude method from NDepend code rule result]

Alternatively, if you wish to suppress a method from all rules results, you can use the [JustMyCode/notmycode facility](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax.aspx#NotMyCode).