# Don't assign a field from many methods

Tags: c#, refactoring, ndepend

I have a class that has a field that is being assigned a value from multiple methods.

```
public class Shape
{
    private Point2D m_location;

    public void Move()
    {
       m_location = ...
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
       m_location = ...
    }

    public void Flip()
    {
       m_location = ...
    }
}
```

I am getting a warning from NDepend that says:

> Don't assign a field from many methods

[https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/Q_Don't_assign_a_field_from_many_methods.html](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/Q_Don%27t_assign_a_field_from_many_methods.html)

I am thinking of solving this problem by creating a separate method to assign the value of the field and calling this method from the other methods that currently assign a value to the field.

Here is an example of the code:

```
private void SetLocation(Point2D point)
{
    m_location = location;
}
```

I want to know if this is a valid way to solve the problem and if it will just hide the code-smell that NDepend detected or actually fix the issue.

Comment: You could create a property for this field `public SomeObject SomeObject {get; private set;}`, but yeah - having another private setter method is also valid as it keeps your variable completely private.

Comment: Is there any reason for that to be a class-level field?

Comment: I don't know your full code, so i can't say if there is a "code smell" or not, but to be honest i wouldn't create an additional method just because the tool gives you a warning, if you have to assign the field from these methods then just do it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, it is one of the parts that this class is composed of.

Comment: @R1PFake I will never do that either, I am just curious how these kinds of things are refactored.

Comment: Then please post a more concrete example so we can actually see what's happening

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a valid way to solve this problem?

No. As you suspect, this is a code smell. What NDepend is complaining about is mutable references; you have code where:

```
var s = new SomeObject(someInitialization);
var r = s.SomeResult();
// you now have no idea what s contains or if it is even usable any more.
```

The solution to this is to make `SomeObject` immutable and return new references instead of changing internals:

```
public SomeObject Something()
{
    return new SomeObject(SomethingDifferentDependingOn(this.something));
}
```

Now instead of your first example you have:

```
var s = new SomeObject(someInitialization);
var r = s.Something().Result;
// s is guaranteed to be unchanged.
```

Yes some times you will need mutable references. In those cases; document them and explain why they have to be mutable. Then you can [override NDepend rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447517/) on a case-by-case basis to prevent it showing a warning. If you have a code smell, warn people. Do not try to hide it.

The example after your edit is quite different, but the general principle still holds. If you have only a few internal fields that all change in method calls you can still return immutable references, e.g.:

```
public Shape Move()
{
    return new Shape(m_location ...);
}
```

If you have many internal fields that don't all change, or you need to do something like share private fields you can't easily have immutable reference, but you can still avoid the warning by using accessors:

```
public Location
{
    get { return m_location; }
    private set { m_location = value; }
}
```

Then use `Shape.Location` exclusively in your internal methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the example in my question to better convey what I want. As you can see, there are cases that returning a new instance every time I use Move() or Rotate() command will not be a good idea always.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, when possible favor immutable classes I wrote a complete article on this topic in the past http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/